# Many "RenderBox was not laid out" for a Row in a Column

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

The many solutions that are already present for the same error do not seem to help in my case, thus the question.

I get a bunch of "RenderBox was not laid out" errors while my Scaffold body remains empty. The error occurs because of the `Row` widget in my `Column` widget. When removing the `Row` widget the error does not occur anymore.

I tried wrapping the `Row` widget in an `Expanded` as well as `SizedBox` or `Flexible` but none helped. I also tried the same with the parent `Column` widget even both at the same time with different combinations.

When looking at the Widget Details Tree in the Flutter Inspector the `renderObject` of the `Padding` at the top has `size: MISSING` but constraints are finite `constraints: BoxConstraints(0.0<=w<=392.7, 0.0<=h<=413.8)`.

Same goes for the child `Column` widget with the following constraints: `constraints: BoxConstraints(0.0.<=w<=340.7, 0.0<=h<=361.8)`.

The child `Row` widget then also has `size: MISSING` but `constraints: BoxConstraints(0.0<=w<=340.7, 0.0<=h<=Infinity)`.

I thought that the child widgets inherit the constraints of the parent? And as I said wrapping the `Row` with `Expanded`, `SizedBox` or `Flexbox` did not help except I did it wrong.

I would be glad to get some answers and a solution. Thank you in advance!

The exact error messages can be found here: https://pastebin.com/n3RFbasT

My code:

```dart
class AddBalance extends StatefulWidget {
  const AddBalance({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<AddBalance> createState() => _AddBalanceState();
}

class _AddBalanceState extends State<AddBalance> {
  final _formKey = GlobalKey<FormState>();

  bool subtractSwitch = false;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        elevation: 0,
        title: const Text("Add Entry"),
      ),
      body: Padding(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.all(26.0),
        child: Form(
          autovalidateMode: AutovalidateMode.always,
          key: _formKey,
          child: Column(
            children: <Widget>[
              TextFormField(
                autofocus: true,
                maxLines: 1,
                textInputAction: TextInputAction.next,
                decoration: const InputDecoration(
                  labelText: "Name",
                ),
              ),
              Row(
                children: [
                  TextFormField(
                    textInputAction: TextInputAction.next,
                    keyboardType: TextInputType.number,
                    maxLength: 10,
                    maxLines: 1,
                    decoration: const InputDecoration(
                      labelText: "Amount",
                    ),
                  ),
                  const Text("Subtract"),
                  Switch(
                      value: subtractSwitch,
                      onChanged: (value) {
                        setState(() {
                          subtractSwitch = value;
                        });
                      }),
                ],
              )
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just need to wrap your `Row` with any Widget that give you boundaries like `Center`, `Align` , `SizedBox`, etc.

In this case I used `Align` and ... don't forget to use `Expanded` over your `TextFormField` inside the `Row`.

```dart
Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        elevation: 0,
        title: const Text("Add Entry"),
      ),
      body: Padding(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.all(26.0),
        child: Form(
          autovalidateMode: AutovalidateMode.always,
          key: _formKey,
          child: Column(
            children: <Widget>[
              TextFormField(
                autofocus: true,
                maxLines: 1,
                textInputAction: TextInputAction.next,
                decoration: const InputDecoration(
                  labelText: "Name",
                ),
              ),
              Align(
                child: Row(
                  children: [
                    Expanded(
                      child: TextFormField(
                        textInputAction: TextInputAction.next,
                        keyboardType: TextInputType.number,
                        maxLength: 10,
                        maxLines: 1,
                        decoration: const InputDecoration(
                          labelText: "Amount",
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                    const Text("Subtract"),
                    Switch(
                        value: subtractSwitch,
                        onChanged: (value) {
                          setState(() {
                            subtractSwitch = value;
                          });
                        }),
                  ],
                ),
              )
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    )
```

Comment: That indeed does solve the problem. Thank you very much!